# Setting up an HTTPS connection on Android with a self signed certificate from an AWS server

Tags: android, ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, self-signed

Im working with a team on an Android app and was allocated with the task of setting up the user login and registration pages. After setting up my server class to post using the `HttpsURLConnection` class I got an `SSLHandshakeException` error. 

**HttpsURLConnection Code**

`HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(spec.toString()).openConnection();`

After some research I realized this is because Android doesn't trust our server because it is self signed. I am trying to follow this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) from the Android dev site but don't understand how to get the `crt` file. Im using an AWS server but I wasn't the person that set up the self signed certificate but I do have full access to the server.

**From Android Docs (How do I get the load-der.crt file?)**

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
```

Comment: That washington.edu url is no longer accessible.

Comment: have you created certificate ownself or it was provided by web admin or backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres how I got the certificate, although this answer may not be very helpful to others. I asked the server admin for it and he gave it to me. I believe he generated the certificate from some bash code while he was SSHed into the server. I then created an `assets` folder in `main` and drop the certificate file in there. I got the input stream with this line of code `InputStream in = context.getAssets().open("my_cert.crt")`.